# Integrate $\int\ln(10x+10x^2)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

The problem asks me to first use substitution then integration by parts; however, I am having a difficult time selecting what to use as $u$.

I tried substituting $u=\ln x$ and $u=10x+10x^2$, but I get left with an $x$ terms, I put the integral in a $du$ format.

Comment: Using substitution on this problem is not a good suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**: $\ln(10x+10x^2) = \ln(10x)+ \ln(1+x)= \ln(10) + \ln x + \ln(x+1)$

Answer (score 2):

We integrate by parts directly. Let $u=\ln(10x+10x^2)$ and let $dv=dx$. Then $du=\frac{10+20x}{10x+10x^2}\,dx=\frac{1+2x}{x+x^2}\,dx$ and we can take $v=x$. Thus our integral is
$$x\ln(10x+10x^2)-\int \frac{1+2x}{1+x}\,dx.$$
The remaining integral is easy, since $\frac{1+2x}{1+x}=2-\frac{1}{1+x}$.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the integral as 
$$\int \ln(x) dx + \int \ln(1+x)dx + \int\ln(10)dx$$
Using integration by parts, 
$$\int \ln(x) dx = x\cdot\ln(x)-\int x\cdot\frac{1}{x}dx = x\ln(x)-x+C$$
And so the above integral equals
$$x\ln(x)-x+(x+1)\ln(x+1)-(x+1)+x\ln(10)+C$$